# ParseQueryAdapter get position of object

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-spinner

I am trying to figure out how to find the position of a custom `ParseObject` in a `ParseQueryAdapter<>` so that I can set the position of a spinner or check rows of a check list in my Android project.

I am currently using a custom adapter extending `ParseQueryAdapter<Vendor>` where `Vendor` extends `ParseObject`. I also have an `Item` that extends `ParseObject` that is associated with a `Vendor`. In this specific example, if I want to edit an `Item`, I want the previously chosen `Vendor` displayed in the spinner. I want to set the selection of a spinner that is backed by my custom `ParseQueryAdapter<Vendor>`. Before I integrated Parse, I was using an `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>` which could do:

```
String vendorName = Vendor.getName();
int position = adapter.getPosition(vendorName);
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

I was thinking that I could get the position of a `Vendor` object like when I was just using the `String` name in the array, but `ParseQueryAdapter` doesn't have a `getPosition` method. I was thinking of making a custom method to do so, but am at a loss of how to find the position of the `Vendor`. I am also thinking that I might need `.isEqualTo(Vendor vendor)` method in my `Vendor` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to facade the ParseQuery Adapter, do something like this :

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final YourParseAdapter adapter;

    public CustomListAdapter(final Context context) {
        this.adapter = new YourParseAdapter(context);
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    public void reloadObjects() {
        adapter.loadObjects();
    }

    // Customize the layout by overriding getItemView
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View result = adapter.getView(i, v, viewGroup);

        // HERE YOU HAVE THE VIEW GENERATED BY PARSE AND THE ITEM POSITION

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return adapter.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return adapter.getItem(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return adapter.getItemId(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out what I needed to do. Instead of using a `ParseQueryAdapter<Vendor>`, I got my `List<Vendor>` from a separate query then I used an `ArrayAdapter<Vendor>` so that I could use the `adapter.getPosition(obj)` method. Since the `ArrayAdapter` uses `.indexOf(Obj)` which in turn uses `.equals(Obj)`, I added to my `Vendor` object:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return this.getObjectId().equals(((Vendor) o).getObjectId());
    }
```

I just needed to have a way for my custom object to be compared.

Comment: I disagree. I was trying to figure out why I couldn't get the desired object. The underlying reason was the lack of an equals() override

Comment: @n8yn8 could you please elaborate? When i call "this", i can't call my object method

Comment: I over-rode the `equals(Object o)` method inside of `Vendor.java`. The `ArrayAdapter<Vendor>` object uses that method to compare objects for `ArrayAdapter<Vendor>#getPosition(obj)`. `this.getObjectId()` is retrieving the current Vendor object's `objectId` to compare to the incoming object's id.